# Problemas com Constraints no PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, constraint

Estou passando por um problema com o PostgreSQL, 8.1.

Ao adicionar `constraints` o mesmo retorna esse erro:
Erro de SQL:

> ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for
>   referenced table "chamado"

Segue o código que estou utilizando:

```
CREATE TABLE "administrador"  ( 
    "administrador_id"  serial NOT NULL,
    "nome"              varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    "cpf"               varchar(14) NOT NULL,
    "rg"                varchar(11) NOT NULL,
    "email"             varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    "endereco"          varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "numero_endereco"   varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    "complemento"       varchar(255) NULL,
    "bairro"            varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "cep"               varchar(9) NOT NULL,
    "cidade"            varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "uf"                char(2) NOT NULL ,
    "telefone"          varchar(21) NOT NULL,
    "data_cadastro"     date NOT NULL,
    "status"            char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    "senha"             varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("administrador_id")
);
COMMENT ON COLUMN "administrador"."cpf" IS '999.999.999-99';
COMMENT ON COLUMN "administrador"."rg" IS '9.999.999';
COMMENT ON COLUMN "administrador"."cep" IS '99999-999';
COMMENT ON COLUMN "administrador"."uf" IS 'Estado';
COMMENT ON COLUMN "administrador"."telefone" IS '+99 (999) 9-9999-9999';
COMMENT ON COLUMN "administrador"."status" IS '0 = Inativo; 1 = Ativo';


CREATE TABLE "chamado"  ( 
    "chamado_id"                    bigserial NOT NULL,
    "empresa_cliente_empresa_id"    integer NOT NULL,
    "titulo"                        varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    "breve_descricao"               varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "descricao"                     text NULL,
    "data"                          date NOT NULL,
    "horario"                       time NOT NULL,
    "urgencia"                      char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "usuario_solicitante"           integer NULL,
    "usuario_responsavel"           integer NOT NULL,
    "status"                        char(1) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("chamado_id","empresa_cliente_empresa_id","usuario_solicitante","usuario_responsavel")
);
COMMENT ON COLUMN "chamado"."urgencia" IS '0 = Extremamente Baixa; 1 = Baixa; 2 = Normal; 3 = Alta; 4 = Extremamente Alta';
COMMENT ON COLUMN "chamado"."status" IS '0 = Pendente; 1 = Em Atendimento; 3 = Atendido, mas não resolvido; 4 = Atendido e resolvido';

CREATE TABLE "dado_extra_administrador"  ( 
    "administrador_administrador_id"    integer NOT NULL,
    "dado_id"                           serial NOT NULL,
    "descricao"                         varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("administrador_administrador_id","dado_id")
);

CREATE TABLE "dado_extra_empresa_cliente"  ( 
    "empresa_cliente_empresa_id"    integer NOT NULL,
    "dado_id"                       serial NOT NULL,
    "descricao"                     varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("empresa_cliente_empresa_id","dado_id")
);

CREATE TABLE "dado_extra_usuario"  ( 
    "usuario_usuario_id"    integer NOT NULL,
    "dado_id"               serial NOT NULL,
    "descricao"             varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("usuario_usuario_id","dado_id")
);

CREATE TABLE "departamento"  ( 
    "projeto_empresa_cliente_empresa_id"    integer NOT NULL,
    "projeto_projeto_id"                    integer NOT NULL,
    "departamento_id"                       serial NOT NULL,
    "titulo"                                varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    "descricao"                             text NOT NULL,
    "data_criacao"                          date NOT NULL,
    "coordernadas_mapa"                     text NOT NULL,
    "coordernadas_posicionamento"           text NOT NULL,
    "cor_mapa"                              varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    "status"                                char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    PRIMARY KEY("projeto_empresa_cliente_empresa_id","projeto_projeto_id","departamento_id")
);
COMMENT ON COLUMN "departamento"."status" IS '0 = Inativo; 1 = Ativo';


CREATE TABLE "empresa_cliente"  ( 
    "empresa_id"        serial NOT NULL,
    "nome_fantasia"     varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "razao_social"      varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "cnpj"              varchar(18) NOT NULL,
    "endereco"          varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    "numero_endereco"   varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    "complemento"       varchar(255) NULL,
    "bairro"            varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    "cep"               varchar(9) NOT NULL,
    "cidade"            varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    "uf"                char(2) NOT NULL ,
    "email"             varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    "data_cadastro"     date NOT NULL,
    "status"            char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    PRIMARY KEY("empresa_id")
);
COMMENT ON COLUMN "empresa_cliente"."cnpj" IS '99.999.999/9999-99';
COMMENT ON COLUMN "empresa_cliente"."cep" IS '99999-999';
COMMENT ON COLUMN "empresa_cliente"."status" IS '0 = Inativa; 1 = Ativa';
CREATE TABLE "equipamento"  ( 
    "equipamento_id"                                        serial NOT NULL,
    "sala_sala_id"                                          integer NOT NULL,
    "sala_departamento_departamento_id"                     integer NOT NULL,
    "sala_departamento_projeto_projeto_id"                  integer NOT NULL,
    "sala_departamento_projeto_empresa_cliente_empresa_id"  integer NOT NULL,
    "titulo"                                                varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    "descricao"                                             text NOT NULL,
    "data_criacao"                                          date NOT NULL,
    "status"                                                char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    "coordenadas_design"                                    text NOT NULL,
    "cordenadas_posicionamento"                             text NOT NULL,
    "cor_design"                                            varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("equipamento_id","sala_sala_id","sala_departamento_departamento_id","sala_departamento_projeto_projeto_id","sala_departamento_projeto_empresa_cliente_empresa_id")
);
COMMENT ON COLUMN "equipamento"."status" IS '0 = Inativo; 1 = Ativo';
CREATE TABLE "funcionalidade_administrador"  ( 
    "funcionalidade_id" serial NOT NULL,
    "descricao"         varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "status"            char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    PRIMARY KEY("funcionalidade_id")
);
COMMENT ON COLUMN "funcionalidade_administrador"."status" IS '0 = Inativa/Oculta; 1 = Ativa';
CREATE TABLE "funcionalidade_usuario"  ( 
    "funcionalidade_id" serial NOT NULL,
    "descricao"         varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "status"            char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    PRIMARY KEY("funcionalidade_id")
);
COMMENT ON COLUMN "funcionalidade_usuario"."status" IS '0 = Inativa/Oculta; 1 = Ativa';
CREATE TABLE "item_invetario_empresa_cliente"  ( 
    "item_id"                       bigserial NOT NULL,
    "empresa_cliente_empresa_id"    integer NOT NULL,
    "titulo"                        varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    "descricao"                     text NOT NULL,
    "data_cadastro"                 date NOT NULL,
    "valor_item"                    float NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("item_id","empresa_cliente_empresa_id")
);
CREATE TABLE "log_atividade_usuario"  ( 
    "usuario_usuario_id"                    integer NOT NULL,
    "usuario_empresa_cliente_empresa_id"    integer NOT NULL,
    "log_id"                                bigserial NOT NULL,
    "data"                                  date NOT NULL,
    "horario"                               time NOT NULL,
    "descricao"                             varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("usuario_empresa_cliente_empresa_id","log_id","usuario_usuario_id")
);
CREATE TABLE "procedimento_chamado"  ( 
    "procedimento_id"                               serial NOT NULL,
    "chamado_id"                                    varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    "descricao"                                     text NOT NULL,
    "data"                                          date NOT NULL,
    "horario"                                       time NOT NULL,
    "chamado_empresa_empresa_cliente_empresa_id"    integer NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("procedimento_id","chamado_id","chamado_empresa_empresa_cliente_empresa_id")
);
CREATE TABLE "projeto"  ( 
    "empresa_cliente_empresa_id"    integer NOT NULL,
    "projeto_id"                    serial NOT NULL,
    "titulo"                        varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    "descricao"                     text NOT NULL,
    "data_criacao"                  date NOT NULL,
    "status"                        char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    "coordenadas_mapa"              text NOT NULL,
    "cor_mapa"                      varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("projeto_id","empresa_cliente_empresa_id")
);
COMMENT ON COLUMN "projeto"."status" IS '0 = Inativo; 1 = Ativo';
CREATE TABLE "relacao_categoria_chamado"  ( 
    "chamado_id"                                    varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    "projeto_projeto_id"                            integer NULL,
    "departamento_departamento_id"                  integer NULL,
    "sala_sala_id"                                  integer NULL,
    "equipamento_equipamento_id"                    integer NULL,
    "categoria"                                     varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    "chamado_empresa_empresa_cliente_empresa_id"    integer NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("chamado_id","projeto_projeto_id","departamento_departamento_id","sala_sala_id","equipamento_equipamento_id","categoria","chamado_empresa_empresa_cliente_empresa_id")
);
COMMENT ON COLUMN "relacao_categoria_chamado"."categoria" IS 'projeto, departamento, sala ou equipamento';
CREATE TABLE "relacao_fun_admin"  ( 
    "administrador_administrador_id"                    integer NOT NULL,
    "funcionalidade_administrador_funcionalidade_id"    integer NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("administrador_administrador_id","funcionalidade_administrador_funcionalidade_id")
);
CREATE TABLE "relacao_fun_user"  ( 
    "usuario_usuario_id"                        integer NOT NULL,
    "funcionalidade_usuario_funcionalidade_id"  integer NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("usuario_usuario_id","funcionalidade_usuario_funcionalidade_id")
);
CREATE TABLE "relacao_proce_item_inven"  ( 
    "item_inventario_empresa_cliente_item_id"   integer NOT NULL,
    "procedimento_chamado_procedimento_id"      varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    "data"                                      date NOT NULL,
    "horario"                                   time NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("item_inventario_empresa_cliente_item_id","procedimento_chamado_procedimento_id")
);
CREATE TABLE "sala"  ( 
    "sala_id"                                           serial NOT NULL,
    "departamento_departamento_id"                      integer NOT NULL,
    "departamento_projeto_empresa_cliente_empresa_id"   varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    "departamento_projeto_projeto_id"                   varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    "titulo"                                            varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    "descricao"                                         text NOT NULL,
    "staus"                                             char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    "data_criacao"                                      date NOT NULL,
    "coordenadas_mapa"                                  text NOT NULL,
    "coordenadas_posicionamento"                        text NOT NULL,
    "cor_mapa"                                          varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("sala_id","departamento_departamento_id","departamento_projeto_empresa_cliente_empresa_id","departamento_projeto_projeto_id")
);
COMMENT ON COLUMN "sala"."staus" IS '0 = Inativo; 1 = Ativo';
CREATE TABLE "usuario"  ( 
    "empresa_cliente_empresa_id"    integer NOT NULL,
    "usuario_id"                    serial NOT NULL,
    "nome"                          varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    "cpf"                           varchar(14) NOT NULL,
    "rg"                            varchar(11) NOT NULL,
    "email"                         varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    "endereco"                      varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "numero_endereco"               varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    "complemento"                   varchar(255) NULL,
    "bairro"                        varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "cep"                           varchar(9) NOT NULL,
    "cidade"                        varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "uf"                            char(2) NOT NULL ,
    "telefone"                      varchar(21) NOT NULL,
    "data_cadastro"                 date NOT NULL,
    "status"                        char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    "senha"                         varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("usuario_id","empresa_cliente_empresa_id")
);
COMMENT ON COLUMN "usuario"."cpf" IS '999.999.999-99';
COMMENT ON COLUMN "usuario"."rg" IS '9.999.999';
COMMENT ON COLUMN "usuario"."cep" IS '99999-999';
COMMENT ON COLUMN "usuario"."uf" IS 'Estado';
COMMENT ON COLUMN "usuario"."telefone" IS '+99 (999) 9-9999-9999';
COMMENT ON COLUMN "usuario"."status" IS '0 = Inativo; 1 = Ativo';
ALTER TABLE "dado_extra_administrador"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "REL_5"
    FOREIGN KEY("administrador_administrador_id")
    REFERENCES "administrador"("administrador_id")
    ON DELETE NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;
ALTER TABLE "relacao_fun_admin"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "REL_9"
    FOREIGN KEY("administrador_administrador_id")
    REFERENCES "administrador"("administrador_id")
    ON DELETE NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;
ALTER TABLE "relacao_categoria_chamado"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "REL_25"
    FOREIGN KEY("chamado_id", "chamado_empresa_empresa_cliente_empresa_id")
    REFERENCES "chamado"("chamado_id", "empresa_cliente_empresa_id")
    ON DELETE NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;
ALTER TABLE "procedimento_chamado"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "REL_17"
    FOREIGN KEY("chamado_id", "chamado_empresa_empresa_cliente_empresa_id")
    REFERENCES "chamado"("chamado_id", "empresa_cliente_empresa_id")
    ON DELETE NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;
ALTER TABLE "sala"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "REL_12"
    FOREIGN KEY("departamento_projeto_empresa_cliente_empresa_id", "departamento_projeto_projeto_id", "departamento_departamento_id")
    REFERENCES "departamento"("projeto_empresa_cliente_empresa_id", "projeto_projeto_id", "departamento_id")
    ON DELETE NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;
ALTER TABLE "relacao_categoria_chamado"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "REL_19"
    FOREIGN KEY("departamento_departamento_id")
    REFERENCES "departamento"("departamento_id")
    ON DELETE NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;
ALTER TABLE "usuario"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "REL_7"
    FOREIGN KEY("empresa_cliente_empresa_id")
    REFERENCES "empresa_cliente"("empresa_id")
    ON DELETE NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;
ALTER TABLE "dado_extra_empresa_cliente"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "REL_4"
    FOREIGN KEY("empresa_cliente_empresa_id")
    REFERENCES "empresa_cliente"("empresa_id")
    ON DELETE NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;
ALTER TABLE "projeto"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "REL_10"
    FOREIGN KEY("empresa_cliente_empresa_id")
    REFERENCES "empresa_cliente"("empresa_id")
    ON DELETE NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;
ALTER TABLE "chamado"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "REL_14"
    FOREIGN KEY("empresa_cliente_empresa_id")
    REFERENCES "empresa_cliente"("empresa_id")
    ON DELETE NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;
ALTER TABLE "item_invetario_empresa_cliente"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "REL_22"
    FOREIGN KEY("empresa_cliente_empresa_id")
    REFERENCES "empresa_cliente"("empresa_id")
    ON DELETE NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;
ALTER TABLE "relacao_categoria_chamado"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "REL_21"
    FOREIGN KEY("equipamento_equipamento_id")
    REFERENCES "equipamento"("equipamento_id")
    ON DELETE NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;
ALTER TABLE "relacao_fun_admin"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "REL_8"
    FOREIGN KEY("funcionalidade_administrador_funcionalidade_id")
    REFERENCES "funcionalidade_administrador"("funcionalidade_id")
    ON DELETE NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;
ALTER TABLE "relacao_fun_user"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "REL_3"
    FOREIGN KEY("funcionalidade_usuario_funcionalidade_id")
    REFERENCES "funcionalidade_usuario"("funcionalidade_id");
ALTER TABLE "relacao_proce_item_inven"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "REL_23"
    FOREIGN KEY("item_inventario_empresa_cliente_item_id")
    REFERENCES "item_invetario_empresa_cliente"("item_id")
    ON DELETE NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;
ALTER TABLE "relacao_proce_item_inven"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "REL_24"
    FOREIGN KEY("procedimento_chamado_procedimento_id")
    REFERENCES "procedimento_chamado"("procedimento_id")
    ON DELETE NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;
ALTER TABLE "departamento"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "REL_11"
    FOREIGN KEY("projeto_empresa_cliente_empresa_id", "projeto_projeto_id")
    REFERENCES "projeto"("empresa_cliente_empresa_id", "projeto_id")
    ON DELETE NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;
ALTER TABLE "relacao_categoria_chamado"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "REL_18"
    FOREIGN KEY("projeto_projeto_id")
    REFERENCES "projeto"("projeto_id")
    ON DELETE NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;
ALTER TABLE "equipamento"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "REL_13"
    FOREIGN KEY("sala_sala_id", "sala_departamento_departamento_id", "sala_departamento_projeto_empresa_cliente_empresa_id", "sala_departamento_projeto_projeto_id")
    REFERENCES "sala"("sala_id", "departamento_departamento_id", "departamento_projeto_empresa_cliente_empresa_id", "departamento_projeto_projeto_id")
    ON DELETE NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;
ALTER TABLE "relacao_categoria_chamado"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "REL_20"
    FOREIGN KEY("sala_sala_id")
    REFERENCES "sala"("sala_id")
    ON DELETE NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;
ALTER TABLE "log_atividade_usuario"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "REL_6"
    FOREIGN KEY("usuario_usuario_id", "usuario_empresa_cliente_empresa_id")
    REFERENCES "usuario"("usuario_id", "empresa_cliente_empresa_id")
    ON DELETE NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;
ALTER TABLE "relacao_fun_user"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "REL_2"
    FOREIGN KEY("usuario_usuario_id")
    REFERENCES "usuario"("usuario_id")
    ON DELETE NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;
ALTER TABLE "dado_extra_usuario"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "REL_1"
    FOREIGN KEY("usuario_usuario_id")
    REFERENCES "usuario"("usuario_id")
    ON DELETE NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;
ALTER TABLE "chamado"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "REL_15"
    FOREIGN KEY("usuario_solicitante")
    REFERENCES "usuario"("usuario_id")
    ON DELETE NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;
ALTER TABLE "chamado"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "REL_16"
    FOREIGN KEY("usuario_responsavel")
    REFERENCES "usuario"("usuario_id")
    ON DELETE NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;


ALTER TABLE ONLY "administrador" ALTER COLUMN "uf" SET DEFAULT 'sc';
ALTER TABLE ONLY "empresa_cliente" ALTER COLUMN "uf" SET DEFAULT 'sc';
ALTER TABLE ONLY "usuario" ALTER COLUMN "uf" SET DEFAULT 'sc';
```

Comment: Por gentileza, nos informe em que linha o erro acontece.

Comment: Infelizmente o phpPgAdmin não retorna a linha, somente: ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "chamado"

Comment: Fernando, tente executar query por query e verifique em qual ponto está retornando esse erro.

Comment: Fernando, a própria mensagem de erro deveria dar uma dica de onde está esse erro, não? Se ela cita a tabela "chamado", então o problema só pode estar em algo envolvendo essa tabela... Não é necessário (nem desejável) se colocar o código **inteiro** na pergunta, pois isso só deixa as pessoas com "preguiça" [justificada] de ler o código todo procurando a parte com erro. Digo isso porque você deve conseguir respostas melhores e mais rápidas se "nos ajudar a te ajudar". :)

Answer (score 3):

Sua tabela `chamado` possui a seguinte definição de chave primária:

```
PRIMARY KEY("chamado_id","empresa_cliente_empresa_id","usuario_solicitante","usuario_responsavel")
```

E mais nada. Isso significa que um chamado só será considerado "duplicado" se **todos** esses campos forem iguais. Exemplo:

```
chamado_id    empresa_cliente_empresa_id    usuario_solicitante   usuario_responsavel
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1             1                             1                     2
1             1                             1                     3
1             1                             2                     3
...
```

Todos esses seriam registros válidos segundo a sua definição de chave primária.

Agora veja como você cria uma chave estrangeira pra tabela `chamado`:

```
REFERENCES "chamado"("chamado_id", "empresa_cliente_empresa_id")
```

Ora, se podem existir múltiplos campos com valor `chamado_id` igual e `empresa_cliente_empresa_id` igual - desde que o resto seja diferente - como saber *qual delas* está sendo referenciado? Só se o banco souber que existe **uma única linha** com esse conjunto de valores, i.e. se eles forem sujeitos a uma restrição `unique`.

Para resolver esse problema, é *suficiente* adicionar uma restrição `unique` à tabela chamado contendo essas duas colunas. Mas **muito provavelmente** o que você quer não é isso: reveja a forma como você define a chave primária da tabela `chamado`, é mesmo possível ter várias dessas colunas repetidas? Aliás, é mesmo possível ter dois chamados com o mesmo `chamado_id`? Ajuste sua definição de chave primária de acordo, e o problema vai desaparecer sozinho (uma vez que uma chave primária também estabelece uma restrição `unique`).

Comment: eu estou com esse mesmo problema. Adicionei um id (serial), coloquei como unique e primary key mas continua dando o mesmo erro :(